# Silverlight 3 - Changing Merged Dictionary Dynamically

Tags: silverlight

**Hello, how to go from:**

```
<Application
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 x:Class="teste.App">
 <Application.Resources>
  <!-- Resources scoped at the Application level should be defined here. -->
  <ResourceDictionary>
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    **<ResourceDictionary Source="Green.xaml"/>**  
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**To:**

```
<Application
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 x:Class="teste.App">
 <Application.Resources>
  <!-- Resources scoped at the Application level should be defined here. -->
  <ResourceDictionary>
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    **<ResourceDictionary Source="Blue.xaml"/>**  
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Dynamically, when users choose the theme... Is it possible?
Thank you
Josi**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the resource dictionary dynamically in the code behind, on the load of the page.xaml:

Application:

```
//Load in resources either from application 
        ResourceDictionary dictionary = Application.Current.Resources as ResourceDictionary;
```

Then once you have the resource dictionary you can apply it using simple logic:

```
//Load in xaml
        if (user1)
            themefile = @"[Assembly];component/Themes/blue.xaml";
        else
            themefile = @"[Assembly];component/Themes/green.xaml";
```

NB: [Assembly] is the namespace of the component where the xaml file exists.

Then merge it into the dictioanry for the page with:

```
 XDocument xaml = XDocument.Load(themefile);
 ResourceDictionary rd = XamlReader.Load(xaml.ToString()) as ResourceDictionary;

        dictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply it to the whole application setting the new theme once?

Comment: What namespace is XDocument in?

Comment: XDocument is in the System.Linq namespace.

Comment: In regards to "Is there a way to apply it to the whole application setting the new theme once?" - you could put the code in the constructor method.